# Running apt-get in aws lambda

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a Lambda function that uses a library lightgbm.
Unfortunately, it gives and error when trying to import it in Python, and says `libgomp.so.1: cannot open shared object file` at the beginning, so I figured out I need to do `apt-get install libgomp1` and maybe something more.

How am I supposed to run these commands?

I assume it is better to use Layers, or something similar because running these commands every time Lambda starts doesn't make sense.

But how do I do sudo apt-get in a particular folder, from what I know that is not possible.

So my questions boil down to - how to run these various bash commands, and install packages, like when you do in Dockerfile, but for Zip file in Lambda.

I am using AWS SAM for deployment and development.

Answer (score 0):

You can run lambda functions from your own Docker images, where you have almost full control over what the image contains.

Here's a simple example of a Python application executed in a container: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-image.html

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

# Install the function's dependencies using file requirements.txt
# from your project folder.

COPY requirements.txt  .
RUN  pip3 install -r requirements.txt --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"

# Copy function code
COPY app.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

# Set the CMD to your handler (could also be done as a parameter override outside of the Dockerfile)
CMD [ "app.handler" ]
```

`app.py`:

```py
import sys
def handler(event, context):
    return 'Hello from AWS Lambda using Python' + sys.version + '!'
```

I use SAM and a Docker image to run a part of a large Java application as a lambda function. Here's what my CF template looks like:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Description: '...'

Parameters:
  Customer:
    Type: String
    Description: Customer ID
  Environment:
    Type: String
    Description: Environment
    AllowedValues: ["production", "test"]
  AppVersion:
    Type: String
    Description: App version

Resources:

  AppLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Sub 'app-${Customer}-${Environment}'
      PackageType: Image
      ImageUri: 'applambda:latest'
      Role: !GetAtt AppLambdaRole.Arn
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Timeout: 30
      MemorySize: 1024
      Description: 'App lambda endpoint (see tags for more info).'
      Environment:
        Variables:
          # This is here to improve cold start speed.
          # https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/optimizing-aws-lambda-function-performance-for-java/
          JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: '-XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1'
      Tags:
        Name: !Sub 'app-${Customer}-${Environment}'
        Customer: !Ref Customer
        Environment: !Ref Environment
        AppVersion: !Ref AppVersion
        Application: myApp
    Metadata:
      Dockerfile: Dockerfile
      DockerContext: ./
      DockerTag: latest

  AppLambdaRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole

  LogGroup:
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
    Properties:
      LogGroupName: !Join ['/', ['/aws/lambda', !Ref AppLambda]]
      RetentionInDays: 7
    DeletionPolicy: Delete
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain

  AppLambdaPinger:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      Description: Keeps the app lambda warm.
      ScheduleExpression: 'rate(15 minutes)'
      Targets:
        - Arn: !GetAtt AppLambda.Arn
          Id: TargetLambda
          Input: '{"ping":"pong"}'

  AppLambdaPingerPermission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Ref AppLambda
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
      Principal: events.amazonaws.com
      SourceArn: !GetAtt AppLambdaPinger.Arn
```

Comment: This does not show any example of `apt` being used...

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski Yes, it doesn't. But also, the question is not just the title, and it solves the user's issue of not being able to install custom packages in the lambda environment.

Comment: I don't see how it solves the issue? Where are the custom packages specified?

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski It shows how to create your own lambda runtime environment using a Docker image where you can install pretty much anything -- even using apt-get if you select an adequate base image.

Comment: adaquate base image - yes thats a large part of the answer missing imo. As you need the lambda runtime configured for that image.